# fadeIn() not working as callback for slideUp

Tags: jquery

I have three images on a page with different animations. On clicking the down arrow, I want the entire viewport with images to slide up and a fourth image fade into the viewport. I have used jQuery to accomplish these animations, but the fourth picture is not fading in.

This is the link to the webpage:
https://rimildeyjsr.github.io/St.Anthony-s-Website/

Thanks in advance!

html :

```
<section class="page-load-screen">
            <img src="images/logo-color-raster-500x500.png" alt="school logo" class="img-responsive school-logo animated flipInY">
            <img src="images/landing-page-blurred.jpg" alt="blurred image of the school" class="img-responsive blurred-school-pic">
            <img src="images/down-arrow.png" alt="down arrow for navigation" class="img-responsive animated slideInDown down-arrow">
            <img src="images/page-1-hero-image.jpg" alt="school's image" class="img-responsive page-one-pic">
        </section>
```

CSS:

```
.pageloadscreen {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

.blurred-school-pic {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.school-logo {
    display: none;
    height: 350px;
    width: auto;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 10%;
    z-index: 5;
    margin: 0 auto;
}


.down-arrow {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 80%;
    z-index: 5;
}

.page-one-pic {
    display: none;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                $(".school-logo").fadeIn(1000);
                $(".blurred-school-pic").delay(500).fadeIn(2000);
                $(".down-arrow").delay(1500).fadeIn(500);
                $(".down-arrow").click(function() {
                    $(".school-logo").fadeOut(1500);
                    $(".page-load-screen").slideUp(3000,function(){
                       $(".page-one-pic").fadeIn();
                    });
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is :

`slideUp()` hides the parent element (`.page-load-screen`) of `.page-one-pic` you are trying to `fadein()` on callback.